# Android activity OnResume called when activity is finishing

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I'm launching an activity from a service when i receive some network packets with the following code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Myactivity.class);
intent.setAction(MyAction);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Sometimes very shortly after i have called 'finish()' in my activity (like 1 millisecond after), my service sends an intent to recreate a similar activity.

In this case, android seams to bring back the same instance of the activity (onResume is called) but the activity then continues to destroy itself... onPause => onResume => onPause => onStop => onDestroy.

It's like if android didn't knew 'finish()' was called.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Calling `finish()` does not "cancel" a previous `startActivity()` call - even if the activity is not completely initialized yet.

Comment: I agree with that but in my case the call to 'finish()' is placed before the second 'startactivity()'. Hence the onPause (caused by the 'finish()') => onResume => onPause ...